# SharedPreferences read same value

Tags: java, android, load, save, sharedpreferences

I've got an app and I am trying to save the username and password when a user logs in. When the user starts the app, it should read the username and the password and login. The problem is, that it always reads the password twice - one time for the password (which is right) and one time for the username. So it tries to login using the password as the username and as the password.

Reading:

```
sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);

String userName = sharedPref.getString(getString(
    R.string.de_letorat_TicTacToe_PREF_NAME), null);
if(userName != null) { 
    String password = sharedPref.getString(getString(
        R.string.de_letorat_TicTacToe_PREF_PASSWORD), null);
    Log.d("TicTacToe", "Read. Username: " + userName + "; Password: " + password);
    pw.println("$login" + userName + "/" + password);  
    pw.flush();
    Log.d("TicTacToe", "Sent. Username: " + userName + "; Password: " + password);
}
```

Saving:

```
Editor edit = sharedPref.edit();

EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_fragment_username);
EditText passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_fragment_password);

edit.putString(getString(R.string.de_letorat_TicTacToe_PREF_NAME),
    nameField.getText().toString());
edit.putString(getString(R.string.de_letorat_TicTacToe_PREF_PASSWORD),
    passwordField.getText().toString());
edit.commit();

Log.d("TicTacToe", "Wrote. Username: " + nameField.getText().toString() +
    "; Password: " + passwordField.getText().toString());
```

The outcome is:

```
Wrote. Username: [username]; Password: [password]
Read. Username: [password]; Password: [password]
Sent. Username: [password]; Password: [password]
```

Comment: You are sure that `de_letorat_TicTacToe_PREF_NAME` and `de_letorat_TicTacToe_PREF_PASSWORD` have different values. Try logging those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your preferences.xml or your strings.xml for duplicate keys.

It seems that both your preference keys are "password".

Answer (score 0):

Each string key needs to be initialized with a distinct value

```
String pref_name_key = "someName";
String pref_pswrd_key = "somePasword";
editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
editor.putString(pref_name_key, name);
editor.putString(pref_pswrd_key, pswrd);
editor.apply();
```